# Build Flex application powered by ColdFusion

Tags: apache-flex, coldfusion

Is it necessary to use DAO Architecture to build a Flex application in ColdFusion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No it is not.  Your ColdFusion code simply has to do whatever the flex app can't do for itself.